# ConcurrentStack: How to check if contains object?

Tags: c#

How can i check if it contains specific object in the stack ?

```
private ConcurrentStack<int> cs = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
cs.Push(1);
```

Comment: You mean if the last item was 1 or if it is contained anywhere?

Comment: if it is contained anywhere.

Comment: You can do it with `IEnumerable<T>` `Contains` method but with complexity O(n).

Comment: You have no explicit method which provides that possibility. Maybe you want to use [ConcurrentBag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), which has `TryPeek` method?

Comment: May i ask why do you need to know if it is contained? Do you want to avoid duplicates? Then i would use an additional `ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>` to track the item and it's count in the stack.

Comment: I wanted to know if the user is in the stack so i can forward the user later when the stack has more users and send the result to the client.

Comment: @JamesColeman: i still don't get why you have to know if it is already contained when you push the user-id into the stack. What you describe sounds like a process that forwards all contained user-id's but is not related to this push-action `cs.Push(1)`.

Comment: I want to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @JamesColeman: i have added a way to achieve this in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52535334/284240).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`Stack<T>.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) isn't available in the [`ConcurrentStack<T>`-class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentstack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). I guess because that would not be thread-safe.

So if you needed it you had to use a lock, then you could use `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
private ConcurrentStack<int> cs = new ConcurrentStack<int>();
private Object csLockObject  = new Object();
```

...

```
bool contains = false;
lock (csLockObject)
{
    contains = cs.Contains(1);
}
```

But while you enumerate this snapshot it's possible that another thread adds or removes items to/from the stack. If you wanted to prevent that you also need a lock where you add/remove.

> I want to avoid duplicates

Well, you *could* use a class like this which uses a `ConcurrentDictionary` to check if it's unique:

```
public class ConcurrentUniqueStack<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<T, int> _itemUnique; // there is no ConcurrentHashSet so we need to use a Key-only dictionary
    private readonly ConcurrentStack<T> _stack;

    public ConcurrentUniqueStack() : this(EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
    {
    }
    public ConcurrentUniqueStack(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _stack = new ConcurrentStack<T>();
        _itemUnique = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, int>(comparer);
    }

    public bool TryPush(T item)
    {
        bool unique = _itemUnique.TryAdd(item, 1);
        if (unique)
        {
            _stack.Push(item);
        }

        return unique;
    }
    public bool TryPop(out T result)
    {
        bool couldBeRemoved = _stack.TryPop(out result);
        if (couldBeRemoved)
        {
            _itemUnique.TryRemove(result, out int whatever);
        }
        return couldBeRemoved;
    }

    public bool TryPeek(out T result) => _stack.TryPeek(out result);
}
```

Comment: The reason that `Contains` is not in there is that `ConcurrentStack` works lock-free. So since you can't lock within the `Contains`, you'd have to redo the operation after every change in the collection, which is cumbersome and easy to fail. Additionally, you'd have to start keeping track of changes in the stack upon *every* push and pop operation, which complicates lock-free access. All of that only for a feature that is useless in the main scenario `ConcurrentStack` is built for, which is inter-thread communication.

Comment: @Sefe yes, i agree that ConcurrentStack might be the wrong collection if you always have to look at all items contained

Answer (score 2):

This structure is not optimized for this operation.

It means, that value lookup operation has O(N) complexity, because you have to iterate whole collection.

So answer depends of your requirements:

- If you want to check value sometimes (e.g. complexity is does not matter) - just use `_stack.FirstOrDefault(v=> v==valueWhichYouTryToFind)`. This can be slow, because you have to iterate all elements. However task will be solved. And please note, that stack can be changed before this function will be finished (e.g. this function can return `true` after `stack pop` operation will be finished)
- If you want to often check values inside huge stack - then you have to create complex structure with concurrent set + stack. I recommend (this is just my opinion) to use just simple Stack + HashSet + locks, because it is quite simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has no easy answer. The reason is that `ConcurrentStack` is designed to be used in a multi-threaded environment, which comes with some caveats. The key issue is that your `Contains` operation has to be atomic. Let's explore the options you have:

**1. Enumerate the stack**

You *could* enumerate the stack with `foreach` and check if your value is in there. The problem is that this enumeration is not atomic and in a multi-threaded environment even dangerous, because a change of the stack from another thread within the enumeration will cause an `InvalidOperationException`. The LINQ method `Enumerable.Contains` makes no difference here, because it will also enumerate the stack.

You could simply place your enumeration inside a `lock`, which only works if *all* accesses to the stack (i.e. pushes and pops) are within the same lock. And then you don't need a `ConcurrentStack`. You can simply go with a regular `Stack`. Note that `ConcurrentStack`, `ConcurrentQueue` and `ConcurrentBag` are implemented lock-free. Placing them inside a lock negates this.

**2. Peek the stack top**

You can call `TryPeek` on the stack, which is is an atomic operation. The problem is that you will only get the value on the stack top. If this is fine for you, you can go with this solution. Otherwise you can't.

**3. Pop and push the values**

You could `TryPopRange` all the values from the stack and then `TryPushRange` the values back onto the stack. I've added this option merely for the sake of completeness, since it actually is totally crazy. When you pop all the values off the stack, they will not be there anymore until you push them back. If anyone wants to pop the top of the stack they are in bad luck. Even worse, when they push another value, you don't only miss it in your check, it will also shake up the stack order.

This all means that you again have to place the whole operation inside a lock, which you can have easier with option 1 (enumerating the stack).

**Conclusion**

If you need to only check the stack top, use `TryPeek`. If you need to check all values, use a `Stack` and place it inside a lock whenever you access it.